# Merging synched data from arrays and sorting swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, struct, zip

I have three arrays of data that I'm pulling in from firebase that are synchronised by their index. I'm displaying this data in a table. The data gets pulled in and stored using a struct.

I want to provide the options to sort the data in two different ways and then display a in the table. I plan to switch between the two different sorts using a segmented control.

As the data sits in 3 separate arrays synchronised by the index sorting one array doesn't sort the corresponding data in the other arrays and breaks the synchronisation. So presume the solution is to bring this data together into a single array that can then be sorted and populate the table.

I've tried all sorts, best progress was made using a slightly hacked zip sequence to populate a new 2d array. But I've failed populating a new array.

```
    struct RTrackedSports {
        var documentId: String?
        var rPostedBy: String?
        var rSyncTimeStringArray: [String]?
        var rSyncDateArray: [Timestamp]?
        var rSyncEventNameArray: [String]?
        var rUID: String?
    }

    var rSelectedRecord: [RTrackedSports] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        resultsTable.dataSource = self
        resultsTable.delegate = self
        
        arrayMasher()
    }

    func arrayMasher() {

        //CODE TO BRING ARRAY DATA TOGETHER HERE
        
        }

//how my table is currently populated
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rSelectedRecord[0].rSyncTimeStringArray!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rCell", for: indexPath) as! ResultTableViewCell
    cell.rEvent.text = rSelectedRecord[0].rSyncEventNameArray![indexPath.row]
    cell.rEventTime.text = rSelectedRecord[0].rSyncTimeStringArray![indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

This is my prototype cell config in IB if that helps too...

[image]

I'm still pretty new to swift, so any help appreciated. Apologies if this is a stupid question, it feels like it should have a simple solution but I can't piece it together.

Happy to share my failed attempts at the arrayMasher if that would help, but I'm not sure it will. Below is a sample of the data I'm working with...

```
[appName.RTrackedSports(documentId: Optional("uVIJJIzs3ux3yZBkRwaB"), rPostedBy: Optional("Dvufj9y2W3ZYB4WWYWcKEuaDOdA2"), rSyncTimeStringArray: Optional(["00:00:20:00", "00:00:30:00", "00:00:10:00", "00:00:00:05"]), rSyncDateArray: Optional([<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1631401200 nanoseconds=0>, <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1631487600 nanoseconds=0>, <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1631574000 nanoseconds=0>, <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1631660400 nanoseconds=0>]), rSyncEventNameArray: Optional(["Tickton", "Beverley", "Hornsea", "Bridlington"]))]
```

Comment: Reading your question, I get the general gist of things, but the code you've included is pretty vague. You say you have three arrays to combine, but your example code has only two `RTrackedSports` arrays. The sample data isn't copy-and-pastable because you've just included the Xcode console output. Can you include something that people can actually use? It's also not clear to me what the guidelines are for how the arrays should be combined. Also, why sync by index? Why not use unique ids? Isn't that way `rUID` is?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, the three arrays are rSyncTimeStringArray, rSyncDateArray, rSyncEventNameArray that's where the data sits when I pull it from firebase.

The rTimeString, rEventDate and rEventName are some empty arrays I was playing around, sorry for the confusion, removed those.

The UID is a unique ID I've applied to the whole record/document not for the three arrays inside the document. I just presumed they had to be synced by index because of the way the table loops through the data and displays it. I've added in the table code and IB screenshot if that helps

Comment: I would say that you should be storing your data with a common ID that can tie elements together. It’s not clear from the post right now how the data structure works, but it seems like this is not the case at the moment, but it would solve the problem

Comment: I've got a working solution which I just posted below, probably an easier way to achieve the desired goal, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so came up with this solution eventually that uses zip to mash the three arrays into a new array that uses a new struct:

```
    //NEW STRUCT FOR THE BLENDED TABLE DATA
    struct RTableData {
        var recordId: Int
        var rSyncTimeString: String
        var rSyncDate: Timestamp
        var rSyncEventName: String
    }

    var rResultsmash: [RTableData] = []

    func arrayMasher() {
        //CUSTOMISED ZIP/FOR LOOP
        var i = 0
        for (Names, (Times, Dates)) in zip(rSelectedRecord[0].rSyncEventNameArray!, zip(rSelectedRecord[0].rSyncTimeStringArray!, rSelectedRecord[0].rSyncDateArray!)) {
            
            rResultsmash.append(RTableData(recordId:i, rSyncTimeString:Times, rSyncDate:Dates, rSyncEventName:Names ));
            i += 1
        }
        //SORT THE DATA BY TIME
        rResultsmash.sort {
            $0.rSyncTimeString < $1.rSyncTimeString
        }
    }
    //LOAD THE DATA INTO THE TABLE
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rResultsmash.count 
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rCell", for: indexPath) as! ResultTableViewCell
        cell.rEvent.text = rResultsmash[indexPath.row].rSyncEventName
        cell.rEventTime.text = rResultsmash[indexPath.row].rSyncTimeString
        cell.rEventPos.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        return cell
    }
    //SWITCH TO CHANGE FILTER AND RELOAD TABLE DATA
    @IBAction func segmentedControlClicked(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                rResultsmash.sort {
                    $0.rSyncTimeString < $1.rSyncTimeString
                }
                resultsTable.reloadData()
            case 1:
                rResultsmash.sort {

                    $0.rSyncDate < $1.rSyncDate
                }
                resultsTable.reloadData()
            default:
                print("THIS IS DEFAULT")
            }
    }
```

I imagine there is a simpler way to do this but it works!